# PHP - preload all classes/functions

Tags: php, composer-php, fastcgi

Is there a way to preload (as opposed to autoload) all classes/functions for a PHP project?

I'm thinking about a web application that runs with PHPFastCGI (so we can bootstrap part of it and reuse this bit between requests), and that uses composer (could its classmap be used for this purpose?).

Here's some context:

"Regular" PHP applications handle a single request and then they get killed. Preloading all classes/functions means having a bigger booting time, autoloading only classes used for the request is a clever optimization but it could be further improved (they require many "read filesystem" operations which are slow), usually by grouping in a single file classes that are likely to be used for all requests (this is what [ClassPreloader](https://github.com/ClassPreloader/ClassPreloader) solves).

However booting an application to handle only one request and then kill it is not the only option: with [PHP FastCGI](http://andrewcarteruk.github.io/slides/breaking-boundaries-with-fastcgi/#/) it is possible to keep the application alive between requests. This allows us to shave booting time off the Request/Response time (e.g. instantiate all services from the DIC once).

While profiling my applications, I've noticed that autoloading always appear in the top 10 most expensive exclusive function calls. In a PHP FastCGI application it might make sense to move class loading in the boot phase to remove it entirely from the Request/Response time. I'm trying to find out (I'll do some benchmarking and publish the result).

For more information about this "exotic" way of running PHP applications, see:

- Using ReactPHP to keep your application alive: http://marcjschmidt.de/blog/2014/02/08/php-high-performance.html
- Fabien Potencier talking about it: https://youtu.be/gpNbmEnRLBU
- Using PHPFastCGI to let FastCGI (e.g. php-fpm) manage PHP processes: http://andrewcarteruk.github.io/slides/breaking-boundaries-with-fastcgi/
- Using Aerys, a non blocking HTTP application: http://blog.kelunik.com/2015/10/21/getting-started-with-aerys.html
- Using AppServer, a native PHP web server: http://www.sitepoint.com/appserver-a-production-ready-php-based-server/

Comment: X/Y problem: why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Andrea autoloading classes for each request with FastCGI seems like a waste when they could be all preloaded once and reused between requests

Comment: Let opcache handle it, then.

Comment: I think that's currently the case (I'm using PHP 7). But I'd like to compare both results

Comment: @KyleAdams are you seriously advising someone not to experiment and learn? Without providing any justification? And people are upvoting this. What the heck…

Comment: There's a ton of reasons here as to why you should not do this.

Comment: @TheWebs and reasons why you should. For example, if you need to run the initialization code of an include file before you instantiate or use a class that autoloads the correct include file.
Edit: Or use a function with 'use function Some\Name\Space\the_function;', but you can't, because it's not preloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using composer, the return value of your composer include statement will be an instance of [Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader](https://getcomposer.org/apidoc/master/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.html). Calling the [loadClass()](https://getcomposer.org/apidoc/master/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.html#method_loadClass) method on this object will include the class file. Thus, when you actually need the class, PHP will already know its definition and will not need to call the callback that composer registers with 'spl_autoload_register'.

```
<?php

/** @var Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader **/
$classLoader = include 'vendor/autoload.php';

$classLoader->loadClass('Path\\To\\MyClass');
$classLoader->loadClass('Path\\To\\OtherClass');
// ...
```

Edit: Note that what is probably more useful in your scenario is preloading services. Actually instantiating the classes your application requires is probably more costly than getting PHP to read their definitions. How to preload services would be dependent on your dependency injection container, but simply 'getting' the service would force the container to instantiate it and remember it.

*OP edit*: Here's the experiment, done on an "empty" symfony application with ReactPHP.

1. Benchmark using preloaded classes, loss of 8% performances: https://github.com/gnugat-examples/bench-sf-standard/commit/c23d681cddc105b3a78f05679b2cffa84657f742
2. Benchmark using preloaded services on top of preloaded classes, same performances as without proloaded classes/services: https://github.com/gnugat-examples/bench-sf-standard/commit/79a16cd3a7184aea6ed35461c4368dec32289ac9

So the conclusion is surprisingly that warming up services or classes before starting a server brings no performance improvement.

Comment: Thanks, that's actually a lot to think of so I'll come back to you when I've done some experiments

Answer (score 5):

Don't. There is no performance benefit if opcache is enabled, and it also may waste memory (you don't always need all classes loaded).

Here is the benchmark: https://phpixie.com/blog/benchmarking-autoloading-vs-combining-classes-into-a-single-file.html

Comment: I don't think this is the same thing as what he's asking. In his case, the classes would be loaded before the process is answering for a request, so the time needed to load all the classes wouldn't affect the response time. @LoicFaugeron is that right?

Comment: @MatthieuNapoli yes you're right.With FastCGI the classes would be preloaded once, and then reused for each request

Comment: In that case there is no point not to use normala utoloading. Because after a few requests all classes are going to get loaded anyway.

Comment: I agree, all classes would be eventually autoloaded. However I'd like to find out if there's actually no point (I have an hypothesis, I'd just like to confirm of disprove it)

Comment: Well, you *can't* load all classes and keep them persisted. PHP's architecture currently doesn't allow this. OPCache is very close, though.

Comment: Even with FastCGI? I'd thought that if you can keep your application alive between two request you could also keep loaded classes. How do they "unload"?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out composer has an option to pre-include files. See the [doc](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#files).
Copied from the doc:

```
{
  "autoload": {
    "files": ["src/preload.php"]
  }
}
```

You can run the necessary code startup/preload, and in your case use:

```
class_exists(SomeClass1::class, TRUE);
class_exists(SomeClass2::class, TRUE);
```

Which is a trick to force autoload of a class.